# JPA and REST - Creating a new entity item through API

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jersey

I am trying to implement a many-to-many relationship between "User" and "Exercise" entities. Here, each user can do multiple exercises and each exercise can be done by multiple users. Below is the code snippet that I have written:

**Abstract Entity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return null == getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (null == obj) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        AbstractEntity that = (AbstractEntity) obj;

        return null != this.getId() && this.getId().equals(that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 17;
        hashCode += null == getId() ? 0 : getId().hashCode() * 31;

        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

}
```

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "Date in ISO format, i.e., yyyy-MM-dd.", example = "1987-06-15")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date birthday;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Collection<Exercise> exercises;
}
```

**Exercise Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Exercise extends AbstractEntity {

    private ExerciseType exerciseType;

    private Timestamp start;

    private long duration;

    private long burnedCalories;

    private long distance;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="Exercise_User",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Exercise_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="User_ID"))
    private Collection<User> users;
}
```

**Exercise Service:**

```
@Transactional
@Path("/api/v1/exercises")
@Api(value = "Exercise Service")
public interface ExerciseService {
    /**
     * This method returns list of exercises for a user from the database filtered by userId.
     *
     * @param userId
     *          the userId of user, not null.
     *
     * @return a list of exercise objects.
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/user/{userId}")
    @Nonnull
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    List<Exercise> getExercises(@Nonnull @PathParam("userId") Long userId,
                                        @Nullable @QueryParam("exerciseType") String exerciseType,
                                        @Nullable @QueryParam("date") String date);

    /**
     * This method returns an exercise from the database filtered by userId and exerciseId.
     *
     * @param exerciseId
     *          the exerciseId of exercise, not null.
     *
     * @param userId
     *          the userId of user, not null.
     *
     * @return an exercise object.
     */
    @GET
    @Path("{exerciseId}/user/{userId}")
    @Nonnull
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Exercise getExercise(@Nonnull @PathParam("userId") Long userId, @Nonnull @PathParam("exerciseId") Long exerciseId);

    /**
     * This method adds an exercise to the database depending on whether the user exists or not.
     *
     * @return status code with error info if any.
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Nonnull
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response addExercise(Exercise exercise);
}
```

**Exercise Service Implementation:**

```
    @Singleton
public class ExerciseServiceImpl implements ExerciseService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExerciseServiceImpl.class);

    private final ExerciseDao exerciseDao;
    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Inject
    ExerciseServiceImpl(final ExerciseDao exerciseDao, final UserDao userDao) {
        this.exerciseDao = exerciseDao;
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public List<Exercise> getExercises(Long userId, String exerciseType, String date) {
        log.debug("Get exercises for a user.");
        if (userId == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Invalid userID");
        }
        if (userDao.findById(userId) == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("User with such id not found");
        }
        Date dateSupplied = null;
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
            try {
                dateSupplied = DateUtils.parseDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Invalid date");
            }
        }
        return exerciseDao.getExercises(userId, exerciseType, dateSupplied);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Exercise getExercise(Long exerciseId, Long userId) {
        if (exerciseId == null || userId == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Invalid exerciseId or userId");
        }

        if (userDao.findById(userId) == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("User with such id not found");
        }

        Exercise exercise = exerciseDao.getExerciseByIds(exerciseId, userId);
        if (exercise == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Exercise with such userId and exerciseId not found");
        }
        return exercise;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Response addExercise(Exercise exercise) {
        log.debug("Adding a new user.");
        if (exercise == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("User details are not supplied");
        }

        return exerciseDao.addExercise(exercise);
    }
}
```

I have added a REST endpoint - /add to create a new exercise. But the problem is this expects all the user details as well in the input payload. My requirement is that this API should accept only exercise entity details and user ID. Can you guys please let me know how to do that? Also, whether "many to many" relationship doesn't fit here? I should be able to query for all exercises for a particular user ID, or a particular exercise start timestamp etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, read a Jersey or JAX-RS tutorial.

Comment: Can you show the exercisedao class code?